# OpenId Connect Implicit Flow with Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid-connect

I'm currently working on an OpenId Server/Client for demonstration purposes and I struggle to understand the following specification.
http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#ImplicitAuthRequest

1) The clientApp sends an request (ajax) to the serverApp in order to obtain a session id

2) The clientApp sends an authentication request (ajax) to the serverApp with

```
{
  response_type : "id_token",
  scope: "openid profile",    
  client_id: "clientApp",
  redirect_uri : "clientAppAddress/redirecturi",
  state: ???,
  nonce: ??? 
}
```

There are no optional fields for grant_type, username and password (as in RFC6749: Access Token Request). How can I transmit the credentials?

Moreover I don't understand the concept behind "state" and "nonce". The specification says that nonce's value "needs to include per-session state and be unguessable to attackers. One method to achieve this for Web Server Clients is to store a cryptographically random value as an HttpOnly session cookie and use a cryptographic hash of the value as the nonce parameter.", whereas state is used to mitigate CSRF, XSRF "by cryptographically binding the value of this parameter with a browser cookie". Where is the difference between them and how do they increase security? I would use the hash-value of the sessionid (stored in http only cookie, and transmitted to the client in the first request) for both of them?

Answer (score 1):

The actual method of authenticating the user, thus transporting credentials is not part of the OpenID Connect specification. The OpenID Connect specification merely tells you how to transport information about the authentication event and the user to a peer. The means of user authentication is independent of that.

The `state` parameter is there to correlate request and response and to share context between request and response. One of the things that you would typically associate with the `state` is the URL that the user is trying to access, so that after a successful authentication response you can redirect to that.

The `nonce` parameter is to prevent replay attacks since that value should be cached.

Together they are used to prevent Cross Site Request Forgery where an attacker got hold of the `id_token` and tries to use it against the RP to impersonate the user in the attacker's browser.

It would be better to use other values for `state` and `nonce` than directly derived from `session_id` since you may want to restart authentication from the same session and then `nonce` replay prevention would block you from reusing it (and distinguish between you and an attacker). Also `state` should be non-guessable, so not the same as previously used in the same session.